# javascript for loop over array with objects - weird results

Tags: javascript

I have an array, lets call it foo. Each element of the array holds an object.

Example:

```
var foo = new Array();

var test = new Object();
test.name = "Item name1";
test.price = 20.00;

foo.push(test);

var test = new Object();
test.name = "Item name2";
test.price = 10.00;

foo.push(test);
```

I should now have:

```
foo[0] => object{name: Item name1, price: 20.00}
foo[1] => object{name: Item name2, price: 10.00}
```

the problem:

```
console.log(foo.length); // 2

for(var x = 0; x < foo.length; x++) { 
     console.log(foo[x]); // foo[x] is undefined 2X
}
```

Why is it that I cannot for loop the array of objects and access them as such? I should be able to say `foo[x].name` (or `foo[x]['name']`) from within the for loop to get the values but I'm getting undefined! any one know why?

Update:

Since that example is way to simplified, here is the full code of what I'm doing, essentially pkgs has [0] populated at the point of running. A new element (this is an add pacakge function) is added then then values are updated. After that I need to use the new insurance values from the two packages to update the UI with the proper insurance values per-package. The very last comment is the interesting part.

```
var pk = $('#shipment_'+shipid).data('pkgs'); 
var pkgs = new Array();
for(index in pk) {
    pkgs.push(jQuery.extend(true, {}, pk[index]));
}
var pkgnum = pkgs.length; // always returns one higher than last index.

// add new pkg to array
pkgs[pkgnum] = new Object();
pkgs[pkgnum].weight = weight;

// overwrite packing slip data.
for(var x = 0; x < pkgs.length; x++) {
    var curPS = new Array();
    var curins = 0;
    for(var y = 0; y < shipmentItems.length; y++) {
        var curqty = parseInt($('#pkgqty-'+y+'-'+x).val());
        var nsrow = jQuery.extend(true, {}, shipmentItems[y]);
        curins += curqty * shipmentItems[y]['price'];
        curPS.push(nsrow);
        curPS[y]['qty'] = curqty;
    }
    pkgs[x].packing_slip = curPS;
    pkgs[x].insurance = Math.ceil(curins);
}

// write pkgs data()
$('#shipment_'+shipid).removeData('pkgs');
$('#shipment_'+shipid).data('pkgs', pkgs);  

// update insurance values
console.log(pkgs); // shows two objects
console.log("len: " + pkgs.length); // len is 2
for(var x = 0; x <= pkgs.length; x++) {
    var insuranceHTML = "$"+pkgs[x].insurance+'<a href="javascript:overrideInsurance('+shipid+','+x+');"><img src="/img/edit2.png" height="16" width="16" alt="" title="Override Insurance Value" align="absmiddle" /></a>';
    $('#pkgins-'+shipid+'-'+x).html(insuranceHTML);
    // pkgs[x] == undefined when x = 1 but not when x=0
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/68Msz/14/

Comment: There's no jQuery in this example, jquery tag is misleading

Comment: I cannot see any problems here. Are you sure that you have the exact same code there?

Comment: I just ran your code in my console and had no problems. There's something else going on. Is there other code in between these statements?

Comment: If I execute your code I get the expected results. So I guess you may have a typo or a scope issue in your actual code.

Comment: This is a very simplified example of what I'm doing, If that is suppose to work I must be breaking this somewhere else. Sorry guys - I'll remove that tag, its just a habit.

Comment: @What's the habit? Thinking that JS and jQuery are the same thing? I would go into rehab immediately to kick that habit ASAP. Joking aside, you should create a jsfiddle before posting a question. Always create a reduction of your problems, don't assume you know what the problem is.

Comment: @Juan Mendes - A bit extreme I think, considering jQuery is just a JS library... anything written with jQuery can be written with pure JS!

Comment: @James: What does your comment have to do with my comment?

Comment: Habbit is Im usually asking jquery questions not general javascript questions... anyway, example code has been updated if anyone has any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/JyLD4/1/

Are you sure this is the issue?

Comment: I guess I have it working now.

I changed:

// add new pkg to array
pkgs[pkgnum] = new Object();

to:

// add new pkg to array
var newpkg = new Object();
pkgs.push(newpkg);

and I also changed the <= in the for loop to just <...

Now pkgs[0] and pkgs[1] are defined and working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have some other code that is interfering with what you have there. I tested it, and I don't get the same result:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/xaTjd/1/

Console:

```
2
Object { name="Item name1", price=20 }
Object { name="Item name2", price=10 }
```